# OGR Python: Copying features from one datasource to another works with shapefile but not with geopackage

Tags: python, vector, ogr, geopackage

I have a shp/dbf EPSG4674 input datasource, and I want to copy features from one layer of this input datasource, create a new output datasource and write these features to that output datasource.

As of now, I am copying all features from one layer to the other, but later I will conditionally filter some of them and write to different datasources depending on the feature's attributes.

When my output datasource is a shapefile, it works perfectly:

```
from osgeo import ogr

ogr.UseExceptions()
input_datasource = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile').Open(r'C:\Users\rodri\Documents\test\test_line.shp')
input_layer = input_datasource.GetLayerByIndex(0)

# UNCOMMENT
#output_datasource = ogr.GetDriverByName('GPKG').CreateDataSource('output.gpkg')

# COMMENT
output_datasource = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile').CreateDataSource('output')

output_layer = output_datasource.CreateLayer('output_layer', input_layer.GetSpatialRef(), input_layer.GetGeomType())

# Copying the old layer schema into the new layer
defn = input_layer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(defn.GetFieldCount()):
    output_layer.CreateField(defn.GetFieldDefn(i))

# Copying the features
for feat in input_layer:
    output_layer.CreateFeature(feat)
```

When I change the output datasource to a geopackage (comment the line below "# COMMENT" and uncomment the line below the "# UNCOMMENT" line), it no longer works and it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gpkg_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    output_layer.CreateFeature(feat)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py", line 1406, in CreateFeature
    return _ogr.Layer_CreateFeature(self, *args)
RuntimeError: failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO "output_layer" ( "fid", "", "ID", "AREA_ID") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

(my layer is a multilinestring layer with two fields, ID and AREA_ID)

I think it's important to mention that my drivers are okay, I have downloaded an [example script that generates a geopackage with both vector and raster data](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/generate_sample_gpkg.py) and it worked without any problems.

I'm running Python 3.6.5 on Windows with GDAL 2.3.2.

Comment: It looks like you are adding too many output fields

Comment: @IanTurton That's weird. When I print (with shapefile as output) the output_layer's field count, it outputs "2", and when I print the feature's field count, I also get "2", so they match. I also think that if too many fields was the problem, I would have problems with shapefile as well, not just geopackage. I might be missing something here.

Comment: the fact it is generating "fid", "", "ID", "AREA_ID" as the column names makes me suspicious